# PHP OOP by simply adding two numbers

Tags: php

```
<?php
    class SimpleClass{


        var $number1;
        var $number2;

        public function input_two_no($num1,$num2){
            $this->number1=$num1;
            $this->number2=$num2;
        }

        public function the_sum(){
            $total = $number1+$number2;
            return $total;
        }

        public function output_the_sum(){
            echo $total;
        }

        $numbers = new SimpleClass;
        $numbers->input_two_no(10,5);
        $numbers->the_sum();
        $numbers->output_the_sum();

    }

?>
```

Please point out where i am going wrong in this.I am not getting the output yet.

Comment: also, check the variable scope of $total.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you're doing wrong, such as:

- Take this code block `$numbers = new SimpleClass; ... $numbers->output_the_sum();` outside of the class.
- See this statement inside `the_sum()` method,

  ```
  $total = $number1+$number2;
  ```

  You didn't declare any local variables named `$number1` and `$number2` inside `the_sum()` method. Instead, you should make use of the instance variables here.
- See this statement in `output_the_sum()` method,

  ```
  echo $total;
  ```

  You didn't declare any local variable named `$total` inside `output_the_sum()` method. Instead, create an instance variable named `$total` and store the sum value in this instance variable. Later, you can display the total sum value using `echo $this->total;`.

So your code should be like this:

```
class SimpleClass{
    var $number1;
    var $number2;
    var $total;

    public function input_two_no($num1,$num2){
        $this->number1=$num1;
        $this->number2=$num2;
    }

    public function the_sum(){
        $this->total = $this->number1+$this->number2;
    }

    public function output_the_sum(){
        echo $this->total;
    }

}

$numbers = new SimpleClass;
$numbers->input_two_no(10,5);
$numbers->the_sum();
$numbers->output_the_sum();
```

Comment: Thanks for the concept.

Comment: @ChaoAbhishekPhukan Glad I could help. *Cheers!* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> First off, you don't need the 2 Methods. `input_two_no($num1,$num2)` and `output_the_sum()`. You may, however, create a basic constructor method. Secondly, to access member-variables (Properties), you need to use php object-access notation (`->`). your class should have been as shown below. the sum method itself returns the sum  of the 2 numbers passed  as arguments.

```
    class SimpleClass{


        var $number1;
        var $number2;

        public function __construct($num1=null, $num2=null){
            $this->number1  = $num1;
            $this->number2  = $num2;
        }

        public function the_sum($number1=null, $number2=null){
            if(!is_null($number1) && !is_null($number2)){
                return null;
            }

            if( (!is_int($number1) || !is_float($number1) || !is_double($number1)) &&
                (!is_int($number2) || !is_float($number2) || !is_double($number2))
            ){
                return 'Numeric inputs only...';
            }
            $this->number1  = $number1;
            $this->number2  = $number2;
            return $this->number1 + $this->number2;
        }

    }

        $numbers = new SimpleClass;
        $output  = $numbers->the_sum(10,5);
        echo $output;       //<==   YIELDS 15
```